# Snake Plant decayed after propagation

Tags: houseplants, indoors, propagation, rot, snake-plants

Just to let everyone know in beginning what happen to whole plant - IT DIED

Now how this happen, I had *Sansevieria trifasciata* with green Center and yellow edges, It had 3 pups and that plant started to become too big for that Plastic pot. So I did what i shouldn't had done.

PROPAGATION

I took pot two inches bigger than the old one and planted the Main Mother plant in it. Note: I let it callus over for a day, then plant in new pot  and did the same for pup and planted it to its new home.

And just in 2 weeks the main mother plant decayed, I'm 100% sure it decayed from root level. Same thing happened with pup .

I lost a very beautiful specimen

Please note I don't have any picture.

Now I stay away from propagation especially Snake Plant. I watched many videos of propagation but in my case not one worked.

Comment: Try using coco coir that is has been cleaned (no salts)  make sure you have neutral PH

Comment: I also had a very experience with propagation. I recently propagated Dracaena and it dies. I Also lost some snake plants due t this. Hehe. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Csy1JYy__PU

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may have left for a week to callus over, all without harming the plant. To be on the safe side, I would do as follows:

Keep the mother plant with its rootball. I may untangle the roots which grew too much and grew around the main root system. These roots are too long for the new pot anyway and that means you should have wrapped them again, which is not advisable.

Repot it. Do not water the plant for a few days until the cuts callus. Note that if the plant was too dry, water it one more time before repotting and taking cuttings, then wait for the soil to dry before you do this.

The cuttings may be left to callus for a few days in the shade before planting. Although this plant is quite robust, you must remember that you cut-off the runner from the mother plant. As a result, the cutting surface (runner's diameter) is too large in proportion to the plant. This (to my opinion) is the main source of failed cuttings.

Answer (score 0):

Many things could have gone wrong.  Not necessarily your fault. Even if it was, it is a learning experience.

If I understand correctly, you divided your plant by removing the pups.  You also repotted the mother in a new pot.

After you took them out of their pots you used a knife or gently broke them apart.  Then you let them sit out to callous for a day before potting.

First, if you are in the Northern Hemisphere it would have been better to wait until spring.  N. Hemisphere plants are in a semi-dormant or fairly dormant state in winter.  Growing very slowly, so it may not have been able to recover from the whole experience if it was dormant.

Its good you let them callous, then you potted them a day later.   When you repotted them did you water right away?  or did you wait a week before you did your first watering.   You should wait a week.  Plant roots get damaged when repotted, then damages need time to heal.

Brand new potting soil come with about 30% hydrated. This is more than enough water for your plant to live off of.  Even if it is an open bag it probably is at least 20% hydrated.

If you used an open bag of soil it could have become contaminated with one or more root rot diseases that killed your plant.  These diseases can attack and decimated a new plant plant very quickly.   I believe your plant was exposed to one of these diseases.   It could have been on your knife, under your fingernails, on the cutting board.   At any point it could have made contact with your plants.

I believe it is a combination of things that happened; The wrong time of the year, not waiting long enough before watering after potting and a disease that was introduced at some point.

Comment: Hi @GardenGems, Nice to hear from you. Well i live in Arabia and if i remember correctly i repotted the Mother plant and pup in June or July which are hot months, Actually from June to September temperature remains above 40 C. For one day i did not water the plant , On 2nd day of potting i water them. But now i have bought new Snake plant with just Dark green and light green variegation  here's the image https://i.imgur.com/FSQWE5c.jpg

Comment: Congrats on your new purchase.  It's much easier to buy them rooted.   I hope are able to enjoy it for many years.

Comment: Just one question , as you can see the old ones have different variegation and the new growth have different, could these be different kind of same family?

Comment: The new growth most often comes out of the ground light green with no markings.  The darker colour and the pattern will slowly take place as it growths to its final height.